# combine subquery result as text

Tags: mysql, subquery, aggregate-functions

**Problem:** I'd like to combine the results of a subquery as a text field, with the results separated by a comma (or any symbol really), into the results of the main query.

**Example:**

*Table 1:*

```
 +----------+---------+
 |  user_ID | user    |
 +----------+---------+
 |        1 |   Smith |
 +----------+---------+
 |        2 |   Jones |
 +----------+---------+
```

*Table 1:*

```
 +----------+---------+
 |  user_ID | roles   |
 +----------+---------+
 |        1 |   Admin |
 +----------+---------+
 |        2 |   Staff |
 +----------+---------+
 |        2 |   Admin |
 +----------+---------+
 |        2 |   Super |
 +----------+---------+
 |        1 |   Other |
 +----------+---------+
```

**So the result would be:**

```
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+
 |  user_ID | user    |   roles                    |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+
 |        1 |   Smith |    Admin, Other            |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+
 |        2 |   Jones |    Staff, Admin, Super     |
 +----------+---------+----------------------------+
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in your question both table no are displaying as table1 edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.user_id, t1.user, group_concat(t2.roles separator ', ') roles
from t1
join t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
group by t1.user_id, t1.user
```

Check the [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it helps:

```
select a.user_id, a.user, group_concat(b.roles) as roles
from table1 as a
join table2 as b on a.user_id = b.user_id
group by a.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.user_ID,a.user,b.roles 
from table1 as a, table2 as b 
where a.user_ID=b.user_ID
```